# Google Places Autocomplete does not populate the address

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, google-places-api

I have an active Google Places autocomplete working with Xamarin Forms or Cross Platform. I have a working solution that auto populates the address when the user types in the address.  My problem is when the user selects it from the list the address does not go to the search_bar.text… The search bar just remains with the text that was typed?  how can I get the text when selected to populate in the search bar.

I am new to Xamarin forms and C#.

```
public Createbusinessaccount ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        search_bar.ApiKey = GooglePlacesApiKey;
        search_bar.Type = PlaceType.Address;
        search_bar.Components = new Components("country:us"); // Restrict results to Australia and New Zealand
        search_bar.PlacesRetrieved += Search_Bar_PlacesRetrieved;
        search_bar.TextChanged += Search_Bar_TextChanged;
        search_bar.MinimumSearchText = 2;
        results_list.ItemSelected += Results_List_ItemSelected;

    }



    void Search_Bar_PlacesRetrieved(object sender, AutoCompleteResult result)
    {
        results_list.ItemsSource = result.AutoCompletePlaces;
        spinner.IsRunning = false;
        spinner.IsVisible = false;

        if (result.AutoCompletePlaces != null && result.AutoCompletePlaces.Count > 0)
            results_list.IsVisible = true;
    }

    void Search_Bar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            results_list.IsVisible = false;
            spinner.IsVisible = true;
            spinner.IsRunning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            results_list.IsVisible = true;
            spinner.IsRunning = false;
            spinner.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    async void Results_List_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var prediction = (AutoCompletePrediction)e.SelectedItem;
        results_list.SelectedItem = null;

        var place = await Places.GetPlace(prediction.Place_ID, GooglePlacesApiKey);

        if (place != null)
            await DisplayAlert(
                place.Name, string.Format("Lat: {0}\nLon: {1}", place.Latitude, place.Longitude), "OK");

    }
```

Comment: async void Results_List_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var prediction = (AutoCompletePrediction)e.SelectedItem;
        results_list.SelectedItem = null;

        var place = await Places.GetPlace(prediction.Place_ID, GooglePlacesApiKey);

        if (place != null)
            await DisplayAlert(
                place.Name, string.Format("Lat: {0}\nLon: {1}", place.Latitude, place.Longitude), "OK");

    }

Comment: im guessing it has something to do with Results_List_ItemSelected?

Comment: Which one of those lines is changing the `Text` of `search_bar`?

Comment: presumably, in Results_List_ItemSelected you should set the searchbar text to whatever they selected

Comment: I am new to c# how would I add that?

Answer (score 1):

In your ItemSelected method, you need to set the text of the searchbar:

```
async void Results_List_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var prediction = (AutoCompletePrediction)e.SelectedItem;

        search_bar.Text = prediction.Name? // Your property here

        results_list.SelectedItem = null;

        var place = await Places.GetPlace(prediction.Place_ID, GooglePlacesApiKey);

        if (place != null)
            await DisplayAlert(
                place.Name, string.Format("Lat: {0}\nLon: {1}", place.Latitude, place.Longitude), "OK");

    }
```

Comment: I am new to c# how would I add that?

Comment: I just put the code to do that. search_bar.Text = YourProperty

Comment: What doest AutoCompletePrediction class have you want to display?

Comment: Thx u saved my life

Comment: It works but it only adds the street name and number but not the city and state

Comment: it only adds the street name and number, not city and state

Comment: @RittenRA that is a different problem. In this question you asked how to populate a text in a search bar, that was my answer. Not sure why you removed the correct tag. Ask a new question regarding the Data, you can't just simply edit the questions everytime something does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am still trying to fix this, it only adds the street name and number not the whole address